# Stimulus Reflex Lifecycle events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, apartment-gem, stimulusjs, stimulus-reflex

This gist is an app which use Stimulus Reflex. It's about a pagination reflex, the thing is I need to hide is the spinner when `afterReflex()` callback is executed, but sometimes it doesn't work.

https://gist.github.com/matedemorphy/94c6ad13b6aebd89862b5b14120c98df

I have this line in config/initializers/session_store.rb

`Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: _my_app, domain: lvh.me`, but then in development.rb

`config.session_store :cache_store`
`config.cache_store = :file_store, Rails.root.join(tmp, cache).to_s, { size: 320.megabytes }`

it could some conflict there?

Comment: Rather than linking out to a gist, please [edit] the question to include a [mre] if possible.

Answer (score 0):

In official docs: If you have multiple identical elements calling Reflex actions, no lifecycle mechanisms (afterReflex callbacks, success events etc) will be run. So i solved adding `data-id`